# Port forwarding mac between two networks

Tags: macos, networking, port, forwarding

I Have a Macbook that connects to two networks. One by ethernet port and the other by a usb ethernet adapter. I'm looking to forward an incoming call to a specific port on the macbook to a different ip/port on the other network. Is this possible?

So for instance, i would like a call to 192.168.178.20 port 7000 to be forwarded to 192.168.10.20 port 8000.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not my strong suit, but as no-one is answering you, I'll suggest this...

You should be able to get there with `ssh` something like this:

```
ssh -L 192.168.178.20:7000:192.168.10.20:8000
```

I think you will need to go to Apple->System Preferences->Sharing and enable the `Remote Login` service first.

Comment: Thanks! I can now connect to 192.168.10.20:8000 by typing localhost:7000 (did it with iSSH btw). But i would like to connect to 192.168.10.20:8000 by 192.168.178.20:7000 from other computers in my network. It doesn't allow this unfortunately. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Or maybe use this... `sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1`
`